# When using 2 authentication keys with devise, how do I make the combination unique?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

So, at the moment I have account & email as authentication keys for devise, so the login looks like:

- Account
- Email
- Password

Problem is though, if a user has already been created under one account, it is impossible to add another one under a different account, as the email has already been taken.

How do I set up devise to avoid this problem?

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the validatable module, and do all the validations (you can see them here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb) by itself, changing the line:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?
```

To

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?, :scope => [:account]
```

Comment: That's great. How can I pull in the Devise::Config stuff to make that accessible in my user model? I tried adding hte line  Devise::Models.config(self, :email_regexp, :password_length) but it didn't work!

Comment: I guess you can access the email regex and the password length through  `Devise.email_regex` and `Devise.password_length`.